# android accessing object inside extended class

Tags: java, android, class, this, extends

I have some problems using `this` keyword. If I have a couple of classes implementing another class, how can I use their values without calling the class itself? I explain.

```
//this is my first class
public class Foo extends FooHelper{
    public int fooInt;
    public String fooString;
    //getter/setter below
}

//this is my second class
public class Foo2 extends FooHelper{
    public double fooDouble;
    public float fooFloat;
}

//this is my main method, i'm using it for calling the value.
//I omit all the thrash code before. 
//This is how i want to call the method:
//imagine before there are onCreate, activity,...
Foo foo = new Foo().GetFooInt();

//this is the class extended from the firsts
public class FooHelper{
    public void GetFooInt(){
        //here is my problem, i need to call the Foo class and the fooInt value.
        //I want also to be able to edit the Foo object, for example:
        if(((Foo)this).getFooInt() == 0){
            (Foo) this.setFooInt(5);
        }
    }
}
```

This is what i want to achieve, acces a class which extends another class with the only `this` keyword from the extended class. How can I do it?

EDIT:

I badly explained i think.
My problem is that i want to access my Foo object inside the FooHelper, not FooHelper's method inside Foo object.

Example:

after using this code:

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
foo.HelperClassMethod();
```

I need (in HelperClass) to access Foo object which invoked it.

```
public HelperClass<Foo> {
    public void HelperClassMethod(){
        //HERE i need to use the "foo" object which invoked this method
    }
}
```

I added the `<Foo>`, probably I was missing it, is this correct? and how can i use this foo object in the method from the helper class? thanks all

EDIT2: i totally failed on my question i thinkm lets ignore the above code and just check below:

I Have to access an object inside the extended class's method.

I have this class:

```
public class Foo extends FooToExtend{
    public int fooInt;
}
```

the class which is extended is this:

```
public class FooToExtend{
    public void MethodOne(){
        //HERE i need to access the calling object
    }
}
```

now, in my main activity, I want to do this:

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
foo.MethodOne();
```

My doubt is how i can access `foo` object i created in main inside my `MethodOne`.

I have to change my FooToExtend in

```
public class<Foo> FooToExtend{
    ...
}
```

but I don't still know how to access the foo object inside it.

Comment: Helper can used as statics.. maybe this will do a better job for you?

Comment: `((Foo)this).getFooInt() == null` this won't work, you can't comapre `int` and `null`.

Comment: I honestly don't know about it, because i'm not expert of this/super being newbie.. but which is the best way to access the class called it from Foo.extendedClassMethod? my problem is that since now i had to pass my helper class, the class i wanted to work with (for example imagine i had to do Foo.GetFooInt(Foo.class). I wanna have this Foo.class without passing it as a variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see 2 problems here, understanding `this` keyword, and `extending` clases

**PROBLEMS WITH `this` KEYWORD**

Imagine you have a class and you are executing some code: keyword `this` refers to the class itself, if you where the object `this` would be the equivalent to **`me`**. Check [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html) and [here](http://www.javatpoint.com/this-keyword) longer explanations, examples and tutorials.

**PROBLEMS WITH `extend`**

Also you must extend from top (interfaces or abstract classes) to bottom (extended) classes and implement in bottom part:

```
//this is the PARENT (FIRST) class extended from the CHILDREN (SECOND)
public abstract class FooHelper{
    public abstract void GetFooInt();
}

//this is the CHILD (SECOND!!!) class
public class Foo extends FooHelper{
    public int fooInt;
    public String fooString;

    @Override
    public void GetFooInt() {
       // are you sure you getFooInt method can return a null???
       if(this.getFooInt() == null){  
           this.setFooInt(5);
    }

    //getter/setter below
}
```

---

## EDIT 1

> Oh ok, this was useful. one more question, a way is to use abstract, as you said, but is there a way to do the same without implementing it all times? just for info, my objective is to use Foo.FooHelperMethod() and be able in "FooHelperMethod()" to access Foo class. I hope i explained it, i don't know how to do it.. if it's impossible i will use abstract as you suggested :)

Sure, this is inheritance, simply don't declare abstract the parent, and implement the methods AND the attributes there, all the children will have this methods and attributes by extending the parent class.

Lets see this example:

```
//this is the PARENT (FIRST) class extended from the CHILDREN (SECOND)
class FooHelper {
    int theIntCommonValue;

    public int getTheIntCommonValue() {
        return theIntCommonValue;
    }

    public void setTheIntCommonValue(int theIntCommonValue) {
        this.theIntCommonValue = theIntCommonValue;
    }
}

// CHILDREN CLASS, look how calling this.getTheIntCommonValue() (the parent method)
// doesn't throw any error because is taking parent method implementation
class Foo extends FooHelper {
    public void getFooInt() {
        if (this.getTheIntCommonValue() == 0)
            this.setTheIntCommonValue(5);
    }
}
class Foo2 extends FooHelper {
    public void getFooInt() {
        if (this.getTheIntCommonValue() == 3)
            this.setTheIntCommonValue(8);
    }
}
```

---

## EDIT2:

> My doubt is how i can access foo object i created in main inside my MethodOne.

**ANSWER:**

Passing the object as a parameter. But then, you need static class, not an extended one, lets see an

**EXAMPLE:**

**Foo.java**

```
public class Foo {
    public int fooInt;
}
```

**FooHelper.java**

```
public static class FooHelper {
    public static void methodOne(Foo foo){
        //HERE i need to access the calling object

        // for example, this?
        if (foo.fooInt == 2)
    }
}
```

Now, how do you execute it?

**Main.java**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Foo foo = new Foo();
    FooHelper.methodOne(foo);
}
```

**NOTES**

- conventions say, methods in java start in **`LOWECASE`** and class name starts in **`UPPERCASE`**.
- you must put both classes in sepparated files in order to allow `static public class`

Comment: Oh ok, this was useful. one more question, a way is to use abstract, as you said, but is there a way to do the same without implementing it all times? just for info, my objective is to use Foo.FooHelperMethod() and be able in "FooHelperMethod()" to access Foo class. I hope i explained it, i don't know how to do it.. if it's impossible i will use abstract as you suggested :)

Comment: @PierGiorgioMisley check my update and don't hesitate to ask more if necessary

Comment: Sorry but my english is not so good and i'm having some problems explaining my goal. You are really helpful thanks. I tryed editing my answer for a better comprehension. Maybe now is better, thanks for the help, if i was not clear tell me :)

Comment: uhmmmm.... looking at your edit, I think you're misunderstoonding how java works, please kindly check the links of using `this` keyword i linked in first part of the answer

Comment: ok, I was totally wrong in my qyestion, thanks you for showing me I was asking a different thing than the one i needed. I radically edited question in edit2, please if possible have a look at it

Comment: ok got it, without passing it i can't use it. thanks you very much for patient and for being really helpful :)

Comment: @PierGiorgioMisley glad to help you, **O**bject **O**riented **P**rogramming sometimes can be really confusing and in the beginings more.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I completely understand. But it looks as though you want `GetFooInt` to perform something differently depending on the class that extended it. So I think the best here to check the `instanceof`.

```
public class FooHelper{
    public void GetFooInt(){
        if(this instanceof Foo)
        {
            ((Foo) this).fooInt = 5;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By the situation you want to named one class "**Helper**" I assume you will use it as a *helper-class*.

```
public class Helper {
  public static int screenHeight = 500;
}

public class AnyOtherClass {
  testSomething() {
  System.out.println(Helper.screenHeight);
  Helper.screenHeight = 510;
  System.out.println(Helper.screenHeight);
 }
}
```

Comment: I've probably choosen a bad name, I wanted to use it with extends keyword, not only as extern class

Answer (score 0):

For some basic understanding: `this` is the keyword you use in a non-static context to access the variables and methods of the Object you're currently inside. Proper use of `this` example:

```
public class SomeClass {
    private int someInt;

    public void setSomeInt(int someInt) {
        this.someInt = someInt;
    }
}
```

In this example the `this` is necessary because the local variable (/parameter) `someInt` has the same name as the global class variable `someInt`. With `this` you access the class varaible of the Object you're "in".

---

Example of unnecessary use of this:

```
public class SomeClass {
    private int someInt;

    public int squareSomeInt() {
        return this.someInt * this.someInt;
    }
}
```

Here you don't need the keyword `this` since there is no local variable called `someInt`.

---

On the other hand `super` is a keyword which accesses the variables and methods of the parent class (the class, your class is derrived from). Example:

```
public class SomeClass {
    private int someInt;
    public int squareSomeInt() {
        return someInt * someInt;
    }
}
```

the derrived class:

```
public class Other extends SomeClass {
    public int squarePlusSquare() {
        return super.squareSomeInt() + super.squareSomeInt();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for those info, I was missing them. But i still don't get how to achieve what i need: I have to use exactly the opposite of "super" keyword. My goal is to use in "SomeClass"'s method the "Other" class by calling SomeClass with new Other().squareSomeInt();

Comment: SomeClass doesn't know anything about the class Other. Other is derrived from SomeClass... Unless you have a variable of Type other in SomeClass you can't call those methods!

Comment: try checking my update, maybe i was missing the <SomeClass> key inside Other class?

Comment: the <Foo> is generics now... this has nothing to do with inheritance... i'm sorry but i don't really understand what you're trying to do now!